# How is atomic time defined in Hartree units?

Tags: atomic-physics, time, conventions, unit-conversion, metrology

As in Planck units, I believe Hartree units have a fundament unit of time, Atomic Time, something like $2.4188843265857(47)×10^{−17}$ s.  My question is what exactly is it that happens in this time?
In Planck units the fundamental unit of time is defined as the amount of time it takes light to travel one unit of length.  How exactly would you explain this Hartree units?  I mean what exactly does it take one Atomic Time to do?

Comment: The units are namd after Ha**r**tree not Ha**l**tree. Please fix that typo.

Answer (score 1):

All the Hartree units have very intuitive meanings
when considering the [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) of the hydrogen atom.

Quoted from [Hartree atomic units - Bohr model in atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units#Bohr_model_in_atomic_units):

> Atomic units are chosen to reflect the properties of electrons
> in atoms. This is particularly clear from the classical Bohr
> model of the hydrogen atom in its ground state. The ground
> state electron orbiting the hydrogen nucleus has (in the
> classical Bohr model):
>
> - Mass = $1$ a.u. of mass
> - Orbital radius = $1$ a.u. of length
> - Orbital velocity = $1$ a.u. of velocity
> - Orbital period = $2\pi$ a.u. of time
> - ...

So in the ground state of the H atom, the electron does one full
revolution ($360°$) around the nucleus in $2\pi$ Hartree time units,
or $1$ radian ($\approx 57°$) in $1$ Hartree time unit.

---

While Bohr's atom model may be simple and intuitive, it is obsolete now.
It has soon been superseded by the theory of quantum mechanics.
According to this theory the hydrogen atom needs to be described
by Schrödinger's equation.

The [time-dependent Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units#Non-relativistic_quantum_mechanics_in_atomic_units) in Hartree units is
$$-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\nabla}^2\psi(\mathbf{r},t)
 -\frac{1}{r}\psi(\mathbf{r},t)
 =i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(\mathbf{r},t)$$

Its solution for the ground state is
$$\psi(\mathbf{r},t)=e^{-r}e^{it/2}$$

From the time-dependent exponential factor you see,
the wave function $\psi$ does one half cycle ($180°$) in $2\pi$
Hartree time units, or $\frac{1}{2}$ radian ($\approx 28.5°$)
in $1$ Hartree time unit.

Comment: In the ground state the electron has no orbital angular momentum and therefore it does not revolve around the nucleus.

Comment: @my2cts You are correct for modern QM theory (solving Schrödinger's equation).
But in Bohr's model (which came 10 years before QM) the electron does
actually revolve around the nucleus (even in the ground state, with $n=1$).

Comment: The Bohr model belongs on history of science SE.

Comment: Why is it that the electron travels 1 radian in 1 Hartree time unit, but in the second part from the Schrodinger equation, the wavefunction travels 1/2 radian in 1 Hartree time unit?